# unable to run Index.js with nodemon . It is showing "clean exit - waiting for changes before restart"

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I am unable to use npm start as it is giving `clean exit - waiting for changes before restart`. What should I do to remove the error
The output should be "port is running at 5000"

```
 (base) parthsharma@Parths-MacBook-Air server % npm start 

> server@1.0.0 start /Users/parthsharma/Desktop/Recollection_project/server
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.7

[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`

[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*

[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json

[nodemon] starting `node index.js`

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

^C%   
                                                                         
(base) parthsharma@Parths-MacBook-Air server % nodemon index.js

zsh: command not found: nodemon




^C%                                                                            
(base) parthsharma@Parths-MacBook-Air server % 
(base) parthsharma@Parths-MacBook-Air server %  nodemon -w ./ 
zsh: command not found: nodemon
(base) parthsharma@Parths-MacBook-Air server %
```

**Index.js:**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ limit: "30 mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30 mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://parthsharma:Pssword@cluster0.fuw21.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server running on port: ${PORT}')))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Comment: Hello) Can you share a code from index.js file?

Comment: @NikitaMazur I have added index.js

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the `nodemon` package from `package.json`. (Simply remove the line)
2. Then run `sudo npm install -g --force nodemon`

For more info refer to [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing `nodemon` as a development manager

`npm i nodemon --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Nodemon as a dependency of your project or installed globally?

If globally, then you've installed it wrong! It doesn't recognize nodemon! try this:

```
npm uninstall nodemon
npm install -g nodemon
```

If locally then, try execute it with node once, see if it doesn't do anything too!

Edit: Looks like the second time you tried to execute it like so:

```
nodemon index.js
```

That won't work! nodemon is always supposed to be executed as an npm script!